# Accept Unix timestamp as integer and convert to DateTimeField for saving in django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, datetime-format, unix-timestamp

I have a model Travel need to accept Unix value from the outside like postman then convert to DateTimeField for saving the data

```
class MyModel:
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
    def ToDateTime(self,timestamp):
        date=datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp)
        return date
Travel(MyModel):
    departure_at = models.DateTimeField()
    arrival_at  = models.DateTimeField()

Serializer

class TravelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    departure_at=serializers.DateTimeField(write_only= True)
    arrival_at=serializers.DateTimeField(write_only= True) 
class Meta:
        model=Travel
        fields = ('departure_at','arrival_at')
    def validate(self, attrs):
        attrs = self.add_departure_at(attrs)
        attrs = self.add_arrival_at(attrs)
        return attrs 
    def add_departure_at(self,attrs):
        departure_at=attrs['departure_at']
        obj=BaseModel()
        todate=obj.ToDateTime(int(arrival_at))
        return todate
```

Postman data

```
{
    "departure_at": "1585750708",
    "arrival_at"  : "1585664308",
}
```

but here I getting this error

```
{
    "departure_at": [
        "Datetime has wrong format. Use one of these formats instead: YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm[:ss[.uuuuuu]][+HH:MM|-HH:MM|Z]."
    ],
    "arrival_at": [
        "Datetime has wrong format. Use one of these formats instead: YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm[:ss[.uuuuuu]][+HH:MM|-HH:MM|Z]."
    ]
}
```

How to solve this error?

Answer (score 2):

Use **`IntegerField`** instead of `DateTimeField`

```
from datetime import datetime


class TravelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    departure_at = serializers.IntegerField(write_only=True)
    arrival_at = serializers.IntegerField(write_only=True)

    def validate_departure_at(self, value):
        return datetime.fromtimestamp(value)

    def validate_arrival_at(self, value):
        return datetime.fromtimestamp(value)

    class Meta:
        model = Travel
        fields = ('departure_at', 'arrival_at')
```

**Example:**

```
payload = {
    "departure_at": 1585750708,
    "arrival_at": 1585664308,
}
s = TravelSerializer(data=payload)
s.is_valid(True)
print(s.validated_data)
```

Comment: thanks Abu this is giving the right working output , but I need to convert Unix value through from MyModel

Comment: Can I ask why do you need that?

Comment: these is the way i  need to achieve this to understand how it will work, moreover when posting we are not getting timestamp in response here.

Comment: you will get this *datetime objects* in your **`create(...)`** and **`update(...)`** methods of the serializer. These two methods are responsible for the object creation and update operations of the model.

Comment: In response to create or update am not getting response showing  departure_at,
    arrival_at  fields but only id
 {
    "id": 47 
}

Comment: thats because you'd put `write_only=True`

Comment: but that fields are readonly fields , if I remove write_only=true then it shows
error->
int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'datetime.datetime'

Comment: I don't understand

Comment: Hi, does the above solution convert unix timestamp to django datetimefield in django rest framework? I am trying to parse unix timestamp from a API data to my model datetimefield using djangorestframework.